# `lein test` fails with `FileNotFoundException` looking for a test clj file I had deleted

Tags: clojure, leiningen

What is being cached? I `rm`'d a test clj file, but `lein test` is still looking for it. I tried both running `lein clean` and `rm -rf target/` and the problem persists. Nothing in my code refers to this deleted clj test file. How do I clear this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same problem using git bash on windows... directory never gets deleted if the device/resource is busy... my suggestion is close all file including your Clojure editor. also you use higher order function do with lein to execute both goals... lein do clean, test